# Distorted Google map

Tags: javascript, css, google-places-api

When using the Google Places API to help customers find our locations we are noticing that the map is showing a gray box over some of the maps, additionally the right location is not showing up

See screen shot and code below
[Our issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWVdU.png)

```
evar latLng = {lat: 40.722488, lng: -73.429957};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('storage-map'), {
   center: latLng,
   zoom: 4
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latLng,
  map: map
});
```

Comment: Does your code actually start with the word `evar`, or is that a typo in your question?

Comment: it was a typo, thanks for your help we figured it out!